# Ajax error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'ID' is undefined"

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax

Hi I am trying to use a simple ajax UpdatePanel..however keep on getting an error
"Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'ID' is undefined" at the moment I try to rum the page.
can anyone help me please in it.

code is as follows:-

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"  Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
   <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="MainScriptManager" runat="server" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlHelloWorld" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHelloWorld" Text="Click the button!" />
            <br /><br />
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnHelloWorld" OnClick="btnHelloWorld_Click" Text="Update label!" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you have any code in the code-behind file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same issue, thought it had somethign to do with my Ajax pack i downloaded for 3.5.
I am using  win7 x64 - IE 8. After I had Updated my IE 8 to IE 9, the issue was fixed. so I am guessing it might have to do with IE 8.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and I tracked it down to the C# class I was using, the HTML code and knockout js. It seems that knockout js links the javascript viewModel object to the HTML page values and the C# class object you're using. For example:

**The HTML page has:**

Note the knockout Id() used.

**The C# class must have a reference to that "Id()":**
public int Id { get; set; }

**So that when you link the two in javascript:**
viewModel.urlColumn1ReportArray.push(viewModel.currentReportDataArray()[i].ReportDataList()[0]);
Knockout js can link the HTML "Id()" with the C# class "Id()"

Pretty cool huh?!